# Laravel class include paths

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a `BaseMigration` class like in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/laravel-4/a7f2fa1f9791). I've saved it as `app/database/migrations/BaseMigration.php` and extend it in my other migrations, but when I try to run my migrations via `php artisan migrate` I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'BaseMigration' not found in ...\app\database\migrations\2014_02_19_071702_create_users_table.php on line 6

Obviously it's having trouble autoloading it. How do I tell Laravel where to find it, or where should I move it to so that it can be found?

Comment: Just running `composer dump-autoload` seems to have done the trick actually.

Comment: @alexrussell: Yes.. if I do have a detailed answer that I'm confident is correct, then I'll usually answer my own question and accept it. Otherwise, I tend to post my findings as comments and let someone else claim the credit if they want to take the time to give a proper response :-) Antonio's answer below, for example, is much more detailed and informative than anything I would have come up with.

Comment: Fair enough. It's good to know an experienced member's protocol. I also usually tend not to answer these types of question for fear of looking like someone who's just out to get the rep for an answer already given. As you say though, there's no harm in providing the answer and some more detail for the rest of the community.

Comment: @alexrussell From my perspective, I'm just happy to get an answer. I don't need the extra points for answering my own question too. Then it looks like *I'm* just trying to get points, even though [SO encourages it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). That said, if no one does answer, I usually like to write something so that I can close it out. Sometimes there is no good answer though, so they just stay open forever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Fixes those kind of errors, but sometimes it doesn't.

To understand if the problem is not in Laravel, but in autoloading (Composer or even PHP), take a look a the files in

```
vendor/composer/*
```

If your file is not using PSR-0, PSR-4 nor file autoloading, it should be

```
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

If your file class is listed there, the problem is in your code, you're referencing it wrongly. In those files you'll find also the way you have to reference to it, for instance, if you have a namespace set on it, you'll have to use it the way it appears on those files.

If it's not listed, the problem is in the guy responsible for autoloading things: Composer (maybe even PHP) and you can refresh it to try to fix it:

```
 rm -rf vendor
 rm composer.lock
 composer install
```